# why don't people wrap DependencyProperties in a generic class?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, dependency-properties

I didn't like how verbose dp's are, since most of the code is just repeated, I just wrapped it in a generic class.

Having seen quite allot of sample code, I was wondering why more people aren't doing the same.

I haven't come across any problems to speak of in my demo application, and it makes the ViewModels easier to manage.

Sample:

```
class GenericDependancyProperty<T> : DependencyObject
{
    // Value dependency property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Value", typeof( T ), typeof( GenericDependancyProperty ),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( (T)default(T),
                new PropertyChangedCallback( OnValueChanged ) ) );

    // getter/setter for the Value dependancy property
    public T Value
    {
        get { return (T)GetValue( ValueProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ValueProperty, value ); }
    }

    // Handles changes to the Value property.       
    private static void OnValueChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        GenericDependancyProperty<T> target = (GenericDependancyProperty<T>)d;
        T oldValue = (T)e.OldValue;
        T newValue = target.Value;
        target.OnValueChanged( oldValue, newValue );
    }

    // Provides derived classes an opportunity to handle changes to the Value property. 
    protected virtual void OnValueChanged( T oldValue, T newValue )
    {
        if ( ValueChanged != null )
        {
            ValueChanged( newValue );
        }
    }

    // Value changed event
    public event Action<T> ValueChanged;
}
```

Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a bad idea, and well worth a try, but it will not work!

You have essentially defined a single dependency property named "Value". This will be OK if you only ever access it via your CLR wrapper (i.e. the get / set  code for your Value property). However, much of the framework affects the dependency property directly. For example, style setters, animations will not be able to use your dependency property.

I too share your pain with the DP boilerplate code, which is why I came up with a declarative solution:

```
[DependencyPropertyDecl("Maximum", typeof(double), 0.0)]
[DependencyPropertyDecl("Minimum", typeof(double), 0.0)]
public partial class RangeControl : UserControl
{
    ...
}
```

The actual dependency properties are generated by a T4 template within Visual Studio.

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2009/08/18/declarative-dependency-property-definition-with-t4-dte.html

Comment: Hey, I totally ganked your code a while back and converted it to create all the custom type descriptor boilerplate code.  It really opened my eyes up to the potential of T4.

Comment: Thanks Will - I am glad you liked it. I am now addicted to T4 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the main thing to point out is that you seem to be doing this to keep your view-model classes neater, but there isn't really any reason to use dependency properties in view-models to begin with.

As Colin's answer demonstrates, it is most common to declare dependency properties in derived/user controls. The view-model typically contains standard properties and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Furthermore, it makes sense to put dependency properties in the derived control class itself instead of a separate generic/static class because you'll need to reference it statically:
`MySlider.SpecialOpacityProperty`. If you have these things in a single class, then you couldn't have 2 properties with the same name (for different controls), or if you use a generic class you can't reference it in XAML.

Comment: Some good points also ... hadn't spotted that. DPs are not really suited to ViewModels.

Comment: Depends, DPs are a lot quicker than INotificationPropertyChanged as I recall. Not that I put DPs in ViewModels myself...

Comment: They are quicker, but it then leads you to referencing UI dlls like WindowsBase.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `ValueProperty` is static, the value won't change no matter how you instantiate your class. I don't see how this would work.

Comment: Dependency properties are always defined as static.

Comment: Yes, but every instance of GenericDependancyProperty will share the same "ValueProperty" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not feasible, flexible and not scalable at all.

Since C# only allows single base class, with your approach, every class can have one `DP` at once.

That is why it won't work.

What you should do to ease your pain is use `snippets` or `code generation` as `Colin` mentioned.

And remember, we all share the same pain.